# (deprecated) /deep/, >>>, and ::ng-deep, ::v-deep who knows what to do?

Tags: css, angular, vue.js, vuejs2, deprecated

As we know /deep/ is deprecated the only solution that I find use global styles instead of /deep/.
Is anybody know alternative solution, solution where we can keep encapsulation or scoped.

Comment: /deep/ is deprecated, but not v-deep. You can continue to use v-deep instead of /deep/

Answer (score -1):

If you need to apply styles to `child` component differently from multiple `parents`, you can always pass them as a `prop`. Simply create prop e.g. `styleConfig`, pass class name to `child` and apply styles there for this class. That way you can keep all the styles inside `child` component and don't need to use /deep/.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but what about third part libraries?